# pass values from a function to another function in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

i have 2 functions in a controller,

```
function feed()
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://localhost/feed.php');

    // pass to other function
    $this->purchased($xml->prices);

    foreach ($xml->prices as $price) {

        echo ' <tr id="'.$price->sign.'"><td class="price">'.$price->wholesale.'</td>';
    }
}
```

in the above function i take some values from a feed and append it to a html in the front end using jquery

in the below function what i do is list down all the products purchased by a particular user. this function also refreshed every 5 seconds.

```
function purchased($price)
{
    foreach ($price as $x)
    {
        $retail = $x->retail;
    }
}
```

what i need to do is get the values returned form the `function feed()` to the purchased function to do some calculations .. but when i use the above method i get the bellow error

> Message: Undefined variable: price
>
> Message: Missing argument 1 for Actions::purchased()

can someone tell me how can i get the `prices` from the `feed` function and use it with the `purchased` function?

Comment: At what line in your code is this error showing? That could point you in the right direction.

Comment: Are you sure the simplexml_load_file is returning what you need? var_dump the $xml variable to check.

Comment: @bakkelun its on the line `function purchased($price) @Craig yep it returns the values because, when i go to the feed function, it shows all the values correctly. cut the values arnt taken to the purchased function`

Comment: in which function and in which line you are getting these both errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood what are you doing and what are you trying to achieve, but..

Passing variables works only when you call function. So, when you execute *feed()* function, then you call *purchased()* function **and** pass variable. *purchased()* works, ends, and then script goes back to the *feed()* function.

Calling **purchased()** from anywhere else doesn't give you the values from **feed()** function.

Try to change function to:

```
function purchased($price = '')
{
    if (!isset ($price) || empty($price)) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://localhost/feed.php');
        $price = $xml->prices;
    }
    foreach ($price as $x) {
        $retail = $x->retail;
    }
}
```